# How to iterate list of object pointed by pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, stdlist

How to get data from a *list of objects* which is pointed by a pointer?

```
std::list<object> *myList;

std::list<object>::iterator itr;

for(itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); itr++) {
  std::cout << itr->data;
}
```

Comment: it might just be  *itr->data

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm. Assuming that `object` has a `data` member that can sent as-is to `stdout`, what you should have written is

```
std::list<object> *myList;

std::list<object>::iterator itr;

for(itr = myList->begin(); itr != myList->end(); itr++) {
  std::cout << itr->data;
}
```

But, honestly, in C++11, it is way nicer to write:

```
std::list<object> *myList;

for(const object & obj : *myList) {
  std::cout << obj.data;
}
```

and this way you don't need the iterator declaration...

Answer (score 0):

myList is a pointer...

do instead `myList->begin()` etc

```
//
struct object
{
    int data{};
};
std::list<object> *myList{nullptr};
//myList=&xxx;
std::list<object>::iterator itr;
for(itr = myList->begin(); itr != myList->end(); itr++)
{
    std::cout << "data: "  << itr->data;
}
//
```